Angular 8 ng-select virtual scrolling for big dataset
I have a multi-select using ng-select in Angular 8, that has to handle 130K+ items which causes a performance issue and throws errors, so I wanted to make it load all the data, store it in a variable, and store a chunk of 1000 items in another variable to be a starting point, then when scrolling it loads more items, and when typing, it does autocomplete:
HTML:
<ng-select
  formControlName="items"
  [multiple]="true"
  [items]="visibleItems"
  [virtualScroll]="true"
  (scrollToEnd)="loadMoreItems()"
  (search)="onSearch($event)"
  [closeOnSelect]="false"
  [clearable]="true"
  [searchable]="true"
  class="full-width"
  (change)="saveSelectedAssets($event)"
>
  <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item" let-clear="clear">
    <span class="ng-value-label">{{ item }}</span>
    <span class="ng-value-icon right" (click)="clear(item)">×</span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-option *ngFor="let item of visibleItems" [value]="item">
    {{ item }}
  </ng-option>
</ng-select>

TypeScript:
allItems = [];
visibleItems = [];
searchTerm: string = "";

getPlaybookTargetSystems() {
  this.myService.getItems().subscribe((data) => {
    if (data) {
      this.allItems = data.result;
      this.loadMoreItems();
      console.log("All items fetched:", this.allItems.length);
    }
  });
}

loadMoreItems() {
  const currentLength = this.visibleItems.length;
  let filteredItems = this.allItems;

  if (this.searchTerm) {
    filteredItems = this.allItems.filter((item) =>
      item.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm),
    );
  }

  const nextChunk = filteredItems.slice(currentLength, currentLength + 1000);

  if (nextChunk.length > 0) {
    this.visibleItems = [...this.visibleItems, ...nextChunk];
    console.log("Loaded more items:", this.visibleItems.length);
  } else {
    console.log("All items have been loaded");
  }
}

onSearch(term: string) {
  this.searchTerm = term || "";
  this.visibleItems = [];
  this.loadMoreItems();
}

now here I have 2 issues:

At loading the page, loadMoreItems() executes to render 1000 items, then when scrolling to the end it executes again to load more, but scrolling again won't do anything and no mo items are added.

When searching it returns no items found


I'm expecting it to load more items on scroll, and filter as an autocomplete when typing.
